# How to get "jssmedia" word in Sitecore JSS app image URL?

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

My JSS app is not showing images though they exist. When I open the same link in my browser, then the browser is showing those images.
I am getting the URL of my JSS image as

http://first-jss-app.dev.local/-/media/firstjss/images/brands/brand-banner.png

However I think we need to get images for JSS app with word "-/jssmedia/" which is something like

http://first-jss-app.dev.local/-/jssmedia/firstjss/images/brands/brand-banner.png

My question is how to get image URL with the "-/jssmedia/" word?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have missed to follow the post-installation instructions of JSS.

Make sure you add the following to your web.config (system.webServer/handlers section):

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecorejss_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media" name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler" />
```

**Reference & Credits :** https://www.creativeway.cloud/2018/09/27/issue-with-jss-media-library-urls/

Comment: I have that entry in web.config file.